# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, liferay

Hi I'm working on a Liferay portlet that accesses the database using JPA. I'm using Tomcat 7 and MySQL.

This portlet works fine in my machine but when I move the portlet to a test environment in another server and try to use it in the test portal I get the following error:

**Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

The database connection database in my persistence.xml is ok.

I tried putting wrong connection data in the persistence.xml to see if the error changed but it didn't. For example I set the user as "wronguser" and when I deployed the portlet and tried to use it again I got exactly the same error:

**Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Even if I change the database name or URL the error is always the same. It's like something is not getting updated. I tried deleting the Tomcat temp folder but didn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "to a test environment in another server" - Forget Java/Tomcat/Liferay, what happens if you try to connect to the database directly, e.g. using `mysql`?  And why are you attempting to connect as `root`??  (I.E., I'm pretty certain this is a problem with your MySQL authentication setup on the new server, and nothing to do with your portlet.)

Comment: If I login to the server and use "mysql -u root -p" I can access the database with no problems.

Comment: I just created a new user (called: test_portlet) in the database and granted all the privileges on the database used and I still get the same error. The error says "... access denied for root....". It should say "...access denied for 'test_portlet'...", shouldn't it?

Comment: Can you provide the info about how are you configuring connection in Liferay? whether through `portal-ext.properties` or other xml configuration in your portlet or through a java class? A code snippet would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I tried putting wrong connection data in the persistence.xml to see if
>   the error changed but it didn't. For example I set the user as
>   "wronguser" and when I deployed the portlet and tried to use it again
>   I got exactly the same error:

This just shows that the username/password given to mysql at the end is not coming from your configuration file as expected, but from to-be-identified-elsewhere.

Until you see mysql complaining about "wronguser" not being able to connect, this is the first roadblock to clear, and the problem is most likely in the application setup, not in mysql.

Should the mysql server complain later about privileges for "wronguser", then sure, the area to investigate then will be grants for this user, but you need to convey the proper user/host/password information to the server first.